# The function "PROBE" on column may be causing a table scan

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I used SQL Doctor from Idera against my database. It generated report in "Query Optimization" category I got finding that "The function "PROBE" on column  may be causing a table scan". Tool provided link http://sqldoctor.idera.com/query-optimization/implicit-conversion-recommendation/ but I can't find anything related to `PROBE`.

If anyone know what it stands for and where can I find the exact details for it.

Answer (score 6):

I don't normally like to do all-link answers, but you asked for "what it stands for and where [you can] find the exact details for it."

Here's a nice summary explanation:  [Probe Residual on Hash Match](http://www.scarydba.com/2011/09/15/probe-residual/)

Here's a long Microsoft explanation:  [Interpreting Execution Plans Containing Bitmap Filters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510541(v=sql.105).aspx).

And here's one that I think might be the most helpful:  [Probe Residual when you have a Hash Match – a hidden cost in execution plans](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/03/22/probe-residual-when-you-have-a-hash-match-a-hidden-cost-in-execution-plans.aspx)

And here's my two cents as well.  Without seeing your queries, tables, or execution plan, I'm mostly guessing, but I would say that the fact that you were directed to that page in the documentation suggests that you are doing a join that requires an implicit conversion.  Since PROBE is associated with hash matches, I infer your join is one of those.

So my guess is that you are joining on two or more fields that have mismatched data types, and that the conversion this requires means that the indexes on one of your tables can't be used.  Without a usable index, the query engine needs to do a table scan, a very expensive operation (particularly if you have a large table.)